# Using multiple canvas & contexts

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to be able to synchronize multiple canvas elements in such a way that when one is scrolled, all other canvas elements will scroll as well. 
However, it's only the scrolling I want synchronized. Each canvas-element still needs to show its unique content.

I have included a rough sketch of the javascript-application I'm making:

**http://i65.tinypic.com/311l829.png**

- Each canvas-element shows a unique set of measurements.
- The HTML buttons toggle specific graphs on each canvas-element.
- If there is any data out of range in any canvas-element, the scrollbars must   show up, and enable the user to scroll through the graphs. **Regardless of which scrollbar is used, all canvas-elements should scroll accordingly.**

Pretty much all of the functionality has been implemented and works, but when I tried adding multiple canvas-elements, it went wrong.

**note:** The initial function that starts CanvasChart:

```
var setCanvasContext = function (canvasName) {
    canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");       
}

var initializeCanvas = function (canvasId, dataObj) {        

    setCanvasContext(canvasId);           
    ...                  
};
```

The rest of the javascript is in this jsfiddle:

**https://jsfiddle.net/ahkemc7k/**

- The program is initiated by a function, *GetData()* that calls
  *generatePageElements()* which in turn creates the necessary HTML and finally calls *CanvasChart.initializeCanvas(canvasId, dataObject)*
  with the id of the canvas that it just created.
- The app.draw() is the function that handles redrawing/updating the
  canvas, after the initializing functions have run once.

I'm still new to javascript and don't know all the ins and outs or cool tricks and coding styles.

**What I think I know so far:**

Currently, I can manipulate 1 canvas at a time. This is because I only work on one context at a time.
It seems obvious to me that I need to restructure my code and how the functions call eachother.

- Do I need to save all the contexts in one object and loop through
  them every time I perform a draw that affects all canvas?
- Should I apply some design pattern with a "main controller" that
  handles how the various canvas' elements scroll?
- Should I create a separate set of methods to handle updating the scrolling-coordinates between canvas elements?

I'm not good at asking questions, so please do tell if I need to reword or add something.

Comment: Insert your code into your post, your text is at best confusing if not an entire enigma.
I would advice you to set a working example and place it here.

Comment: btw working with multiple canvases in a single file or several is simple, var canvas1 = ..., context1 = canvas1.getContext(...), canvas2= ..., context2 = canvas2.getContext(...); then use appropriate context.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and reword my question a bit later, and see if I can throw up some sensible code. The problem is that there are variable factors that determine how many canvas' are actually used at any given moment. The code itself is dependendt on a webservice to even show some data, so I'm not certain if it will work. I will give it a try soon :)

I'm really bad at expressing myself, I've noticed.

Comment: I would like to help, but I still can't quite figure out what the issue is, however in answer the last point yes, it's a good idea to store all of your contexts in an array and loop through them for each draw call, that way you can replicate transformations on all of them to keep them synchronised

Comment: I've tried rewording a bit and adding all the code. Thanks for the tip Hayko, I'm trying to see how to make that work, but it seems I will need to refactor/change the structure of my function calls.

I can't really post a working example, because it depends on a local webservice (and a c# data.asmx file), so without it, it won't show anything.